# Using pointer to non-initialized member in initializer list

Tags: c++, pointers, initializer-list

I don't know if I managed to describe what I mean in the title but say that we have a class Data like so:

```
class Data
{
public:
    Data(int i) : m_data(i) {} // Must always be initialized with a value
    int m_data;
};
```

And a Main class like so:

```
class Main
{
public:
    Main() :
        m_data(Set(&m_data)) // Is it ok to use the pointer of m_data like this?
    {
    }

private:
    int Set(Data* pData)
    {
        m_pData = pData;
        return 10;
    }

    Data* m_pData;
    Data m_data; //Must be initialized in the initializer list of the constructor
};
```

My question is:
Can I safely give &m_data as pointer to the Set function before actually initializing m_data? (assuming the pointer isn't used in the Set function, only stored)
i.e; is the &m_data pointer valid before m_data itself is initialized?

Comment: Why not just use &m_data when you need it?

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Well obviously this is needlessly complicated and not "production" code. I simply wanted to know IF it was legal :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I safely give `&m_data` as pointer to the `Set` function before actually initializing `m_data`?

Absolutely, you can do that: it would be illegal to read from the pointer until the memory has been written at least once, but the pointer itself is safe to store.

Comment: +1 for "it is legal to store a pointer to uninitialized memory", -1 for "oh, and you can write to an uninitialized type with `operator=` no problem!".  No, calling `operator=` on a dereferenced pointer to an arbitrary class which has not been constructed is not safe.  Heck, even if `Data` is an `int`, the compiler would be free to overwrite it with `0xBAADF00D` when it is initialized in the constructor I suspect, making your `=0` fail to act as expected.  Or, it could `0xBAADF00D` your memory prior to calling the constructor, and `Assert` that it is still `0xBAADF00D` when initialized...

Comment: @Yakk Oops, I misread the question, I thought that was `m_data` of type `int` (that's why I wrote ` = 0`). Thanks for the correction!

Comment: Excellent, short and sweet! Thanks.